# Using Case When inside Constructor JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, dto

I'm currently try to query via constructor in JPQL. For example:

`em` here is the `EntityManager`

```
em.createQuery("SELECT NEW {packagePath}.UserDTO(name, status) FROM User", UserDTO.class);
```

But I want to use Case When in `status` so I tried to query:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT NEW {packagePath}.UserDTO(name, case when status = 'A' then '1' else '0' end as status) FROM User", UserDTO.class);
```

I tried to query this in SQL Developer:

```
SELECT name, CASE WHEN status = 'A' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS status FROM User
```

and it works perfectly fine.

Where the sample DTO:

**UserDTO.class**

```
public class UserDTO {
    private String name;
    private Character status;

    // Suggested by Viacheslav Shalamov but not working.
    public UserDTO(){}

    // EDIT
    public UserDTO(String name, Character status){
         this.name = name;
         this.status = status;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: User.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(100)")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "pc_no", length = 3, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(3)")
    private String pc_no;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Character status;

    // constructor / get and set
}
```

Error:

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.lang.String.
```

Is there any other way to include the `Case When` method? If not, please give me some advice on how to do this in a different approach. Thank you.

Comment: can you please add declaration of `UserDTO` constructor

Comment: Please see updated content.

Comment: I think JPQL searchs for a String, String Constructor, wich is absent, since you provide a String, Character-Constructor

Comment: So the "Case When" method there converted the output to String?

Comment: If it's not a String anyway, does ´em.createQuery("SELECT NEW {packagePath}.UserDTO(name, status) FROM User", UserDTO.class);´ work?

Comment: Yes. It is working. So then I tried to do the second query but no luck.

Comment: Then yes. The char in User will be converted to a String in the case-Statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a way to convert your VARCHAR2 `status` from `String` to `Character` in the failing query.

try this:

```
public class UserDTO {
    private String name;
    private Character status;

    public UserDTO(String name, String status){
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using "NEW" keyword in JPQL needs to specify a constructor. So if I remove the constructor, error must have a constructor right?

Comment: error message `Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.lang.String.` suggest that it not about empty one

Comment: I tried your answer but not working and "status" is a Character.

Comment: What are types of your `User` table columns?

Comment: For name: VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) and for status: VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)

Comment: I think the VARCHAR2(1  CHAR) is still implicitly interpreted as a String, not as a Character.

Comment: I will add sample User class

Comment: Yes this is what I did and it worked. But @Turo provides the same logic first.

Answer (score 1):

The error-messages seams to tell that the Case-Statement returns a String, so you have to provide a String,String-constructer to handle that case, too.

But you could also handle the conversion convinienttly in the existing constructor to avoid the case-statement.

Comment: Im thinking about accepting your answer but in order to help future researchers, I will accept @Viacheslav Shalamov 's answer. Hope you understand. I very much appreciated your answer.